# R loop to standardize variables using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

how can I loop over certain variables in order to standardize them? I am strying to set up the code but it's not working, my idea was to use `assign` or `eval` but those seem not working. Below a reproducible working example.

```
if (!require('data.table')) {install.packages('data.table'); library('data.table')}

a <- seq(0,10,1)
b <- seq(99,100,0.1)

dt <- data.table(a,b)

# Expected result
dt[,z_a:= ((a-mean(a,na.rm=TRUE))/sd(a,na.rm=TRUE)) ]
dt[,z_b:= ((a-mean(a,na.rm=TRUE))/sd(a,na.rm=TRUE)) ]

# Loop not working
stdvars <- c(a,b)

for (v in stdvars) {

  dt[z_v:= ((v-mean(v,na.rm=TRUE))/sd(v,na.rm=TRUE)) ]

}
dt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against using explicit loops when working with `data.table`, as its internal functionality is many times more efficient. In particular, you can define a function which you call through `lapply` over a specified subset (`.SD`):

```
standardise = function(x){(x-mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))/sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)} # Define a standardising function

oldcols = c('a', 'b') # Name of old columns
newcols = paste0('z_', oldcols) # Name of new columns ('z_a' and 'z_b')

dt[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, standardise), .SDcols = oldcols]
```

Output:

```
> dt
     a     b        z_a        z_b
 1:  0  99.0 -1.5075567 -1.5075567
 2:  1  99.1 -1.2060454 -1.2060454
 3:  2  99.2 -0.9045340 -0.9045340
 4:  3  99.3 -0.6030227 -0.6030227
 5:  4  99.4 -0.3015113 -0.3015113
 6:  5  99.5  0.0000000  0.0000000
 7:  6  99.6  0.3015113  0.3015113
 8:  7  99.7  0.6030227  0.6030227
 9:  8  99.8  0.9045340  0.9045340
10:  9  99.9  1.2060454  1.2060454
11: 10 100.0  1.5075567  1.5075567
```

`.SD` means that you are calling a `lapply` across a **S**ubset of the **D**ata, defined by the `.SDcols` argument. In this case, we define `newcols` as the application of `standardise` function across the subset `oldcols`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function `scale` which allows to standardize variables.
The missing values are removed when standardizing.
So it would be more direct to proceed as follows:

```
cols <- c("a", "b")
dt[, paste0("z_", cols) := lapply(.SD, scale), .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use non-standard evaluation:

```
for (v in c("a", "b")) {
    eval(substitute(dt[, paste0("z_", v) := (V - mean(V, na.rm=TRUE)) / sd(V, na.rm=TRUE)],
        list(V=as.name(v))))
}
dt
```

Or putting it in a function:

```
f <- function(DT, v) {
    lhs <- paste0("z_", as.list(match.call())$v)
    eval(substitute(
        DT[, (lhs) := (v - mean(v, na.rm=TRUE)) / sd(v, na.rm=TRUE)]))
}
f(dt, a)
f(dt, b)
dt
```