# Error in the standardization of variables

Tags: r, standardization

I'm trying to standardize my variables by using a code that I found in a previous question [R loop to standardize variables using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60658004/21208453) However, I got an error message, so I'm not sure what the reason is.

```
standardise = function(x){(x-mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))/sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)} # Define a standardising function

oldcols = c('B', 'ARP') # Name of old columns
newcols = paste0('z_', oldcols) # Name of new columns ('z_B' and 'z_ARP')

QBB_clean[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, standardise), .SDcols = oldcols]
```

> The error message (Error in `:=`((newcols), lapply(.SD, standardise)) :
> could not find function ":=")

Comment: Did you load `data.table` with `library(data.table)`?

Comment: @mhovd Thank you for your response. Now that I have applied it, I have received another error message. (Error in :=((newcols), lapply(.SD, standardise)) : Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and :=(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").)